# Why does this for loop only work if it iterates at the zeroth index?

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, for-loop, iteration

I have a list:

```
oldlist = ['do gs\n','ca ts\n','monk eys\n','fro     gs\n','\n','lio     ns\n','tige rs\n','she ep\n']
```

I'm trying to extract only the **first** portion of the list **['do gs\n', 'ca ts\n', 'monk eys\n', 'fro gs\n']** before the newline **'\n'**.

This is my code and it outputs the correct solution:

```
oldlist = ['do gs\n','ca ts\n','monk eys\n','fro     gs\n','\n','lio ns\n','tige rs\n','she ep\n']
print("Before Loop: ", oldlist)
newlist = []
for iter in oldlist:
    if '\n' in iter[0]:
        break
    else:
        newlist.append(iter)

print("After Loop: ", newlist)
```

However the line which begins from

```
if '\n' in iter[0]:
```

is the one which I do not understand how it works. Why does this loop only work when **iter[0]**? Why is it that if I just iterate over iter it outputs only a blank list?

**OUTPUT if "iter[0]" used:**

```
Before Loop:  ['do gs\n', 'ca ts\n', 'monk eys\n', 'fro gs\n', '\n', 'lio ns\n', 'tige rs\n', 'she ep\n']
After Loop:  ['do gs\n', 'ca ts\n', 'monk eys\n', 'fro gs\n']
```

**OUTPUT if "iter" used :**

```
Before Loop:  ['do gs\n', 'ca ts\n', 'monk eys\n', 'fro gs\n', '\n', 'lio ns\n', 'tige rs\n', 'she ep\n']
After Loop:  []
```

Also if I do this:

```
for iter in oldlist:
     print(iter[0])
```

It spits out only **d** from the first string **do gs\n**

So in summary, what is going on behind the scenes that is allowing iter[0] to iterate through the oldlist to give the correct solution in newlist?

Comment: Calling something `iter` won't do you any good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `in` operator when used on strings checks if a given character exists at all in the string. So `\n in "do gs\n"` evaluates to true, because there is a newline character in this string. However, if you check for `\n in "do gs\n"[0]` it only checks if the first character is the newline.

It would be more clear if you simply did `if iter == '\n'` since that's basically what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your `iter[0]` means the first character in each string while `iter` means each full string. eg `'do gs\n'[0]` means `'d'` and of course in `'do gs\n'` there is a `'\n'`.

You can also use the shorter `newlist=oldlist[:oldlist.index("\n")]` instead of your loop.